# Is this crash in libc++ std::search_n a bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, libc++

I've narrowed this down as far as I can, it seems like a bug...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Crashes
  std::vector<uint8_t> bs{1, 0, 0};
  std::search_n(bs.begin(), bs.end(), 3, 1);

  // Does not crash
  std::vector<uint8_t> bs{1, 0};
  std::search_n(bs.begin(), bs.end(), 2, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

I get

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I hope I'm not using std::search_n incorrectly :)

Stepping through the STL implementation doesn't seem possible at present, using LLDB.

version info:

```
$clang --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Evidence ;)

```
13:06:47 ~/bug$ cat bug.cc
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<uint8_t> bs{1, 0, 0};
  std::search_n(bs.begin(), bs.end(), 3, 1);

  // std::vector<uint8_t> bs{1, 0};
  // std::search_n(bs.begin(), bs.end(), 2, 1);

  return 0;
}
13:06:52 ~/bug$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ bug.cc -o bug
13:07:36 ~/bug$ ./bug
Segmentation fault: 11
13:07:42 ~/bug$
```

Comment: Doesn't crash with clang 3.2: [http://liveworkspace.org/code/tRPXH$2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/tRPXH$2)

Comment: Works fine with the GNU libstdc++, and there's nothing fishy about your use of `find_n` (except that you're not using the return value and that with these inputs the search will always fail).

Comment: @interjay but is liveworkspace using libc++ or libstdc++?

Comment: It's very likely that you simplified your code too much. Does your program still crash in this minimal example?

Comment: Works fine with gcc 4.5.3

Comment: The code in the second block does not compile with ideone http://ideone.com/w0NOS4

Comment: @0A0D You missed the C++11 flag I believe.

Comment: @dpj: ideone compiles with C++11 flag (did you see the warning?) ideone runs 4.7.2 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14610855/195488)

Comment: @0A0D which warning?!

Comment: @dpj: If you actually clicked on the ideone link I originally provided, you will see it.

Comment: The type you want is declared in `<cstddef>` and goes by the name of `std::uint8_t`. Not that this is at all related to the problem at hand...

Comment: @rubenvb: I know that, but if you are going to post code - it might as well work

Comment: @0A0D It does work: http://ideone.com/ScxCGv. You missed the compiler flag.

Comment: @MichaelWild: Oh, I didn't notice that it was with a different stdlib. liveworkspace appears to use libstdc++.

Comment: @dpj: No, it works, but you have to include the <cstddef>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in search_n, it crashes for me too (Xcode 4.6.1). I think in __search_n the test

```
if (__first == __s)  // return __last if no element matches __value_
```

needs to be

```
if (__first >= __s)  // return __last if no element matches __value_
```

What happens is that the algorithm starts matching, then mismatches and starts over; this new startpoint is beyond __s which is the logical last possible starting point for the length of the pattern. The old test only tested for equality, not "beyondness". With the fix it doesn't crash for me any more.

Comment: I suppose this should be filed, do you have an account to do this? http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi

Comment: No, I don't. (adding chars to meet 15 chars requirement)

Comment: Agreed that this is the right fix.  Thanks for both the bug report and the fix.  Committed revision 178764.

Comment: I'm not sure you can compare iterators this way. Consider a deque where the iterators "point to" different allocated blocks of memory.  What about `distance(first, last) < distance(s, last)`?